# Bugs while typing up answers and posts

Tags: bug

While typing answers and posts, on Android Chrome with the 'full site' option on, multiple bugs seem to arise; letters get randomly capitalised, duplicated, and start to come out of nowhere. Backspacing sometimes messes stuff up even further; words tend to duplicate when I do so. See the last typed paragraph in the below screenshot, which I've left unedited to show how this happens;

[image: screenshot]

This has shown up multiple times when I use the site; it doesn't seem recent. I don't think it's due to me typing like a maniac, either; I checked while I was typing up the stuff in the screenshot, and I wasn't unintentionally hitting the 'capitalise' key.

Is it a site-wide bug, or am I doing something wrong? How can I fix it?

**Update:** here's a [gif](https://gfycat.com/slushysmallaustraliancurlew) of the problem. I tried typing letters one be one, without touching any key other than the intended ones, and the errors persist. Things get even worse when I type at normal speeds, but even slow typing is difficult like this.

Comment: I don't have that, and I use the "full site" on my phone *a lot*. It looks like mistypes. These happen on a small keyboard. The "a" clicks the shift key, when you try to undo it, you accidentally press it again, etc. You don't need to type like a maniac. Just a tad less careful than perfect will lead to the same conclusion in some cases.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I suppose most of it could be explained by how I type, but there's the case of words and letters randomly multiplying when I do something. If by the shift key you mean the one that capitalizes letters, I took special care not to touch it when typing the stuff in the screenshot, and it still persists. It seemed to stop when I switched from GBoard to Samsung's keyboard, though.

Comment: The Android keyboard is prone to mistaking letter "a" for a single shift-key press, resulting in both the omission of letter "a" and the unintended capitalization of the next letter.

Comment: @hardmath: hmm. I'm still pretty sure it wasn't anything like that from when I typed and checked, but if it doesn't happen for anyone else I suppose it *is* my unholy typing. Thanks, I'll see to it.

Comment: I do see something similar on my Android device, but it is not frequent and is related to my keyboard app. You may try to change the keyboard app and see if that helps.

Comment: I also experience this, but not only on Math.SE.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I've uploaded a gif of it.

Comment: Again, I am sorry that you have this problem, but I don't think it's an SE problem.

Comment: We can wait a while to see if anyone **not** using Android has this problem.

Comment: You may try to disable autocorrect feature in your keyboard app. Over time, a lot of wrong autocorrect words get saved in the app database (due to accidental/wrong touch).